# How to remove space between form group row itens?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

How to remove the space between button and two inputs in form div #roleSearch ? (#inputCode + #btnOpenSearch + #inputDescription)

```
<div id="roleSearch" class="col-md-2 ">
    <input  id="inputCode" type="text" class="form-control int-number col-sm-1" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <!-- Open a popup to search the code -->
        <a id="btnOpenSearch" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <input id="inputDescription" type="text" class="form-control col-md-9 " />
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/computeiro/rfehs6bg/72/

Comment: You could use negative margins. However, your fiddle doesn't actually include the code you've posted above. Please update your question to include a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: can't understand anything from your fiddle.

Comment: please add correct fiddle....

Comment: You also have a close </input> tag which is not supposed to be there.

Comment: @AmitKumar I'm so sorry, The link was wrong, now I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you want ? remove space only or all things  (#inputCode + #btnOpenSearch + #inputDescription) gone into a single line.

i solve this plz saw this link

```
<div class="row">
<form>
    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
        <label for="inputCnpj">Patner</label>
        <div class="entity-search form-group row input-group" style="display: table" > 
            <div class="col-md-2 p0" style="display: table-cell">
                <input  type="text" class="form-control int-number" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 p0" style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: top;">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/amitmonsterme/1o0rhq1b/2/

Comment: Thank you, now I will remove border radius = )